# Why isn't my NSTimer working?

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

I want to call the function foo repeatedly but the nstimer isnt working.can you please help me?

```
@implementation abc
-(id)init
{
   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1/16) target:self selector:@selector(foo) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

This is my main

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    abc *ab=[[abc alloc]init];



    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:100];


    [ab release];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with threading, but looking at the documentation it looks like this line [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:100]; blocks everything running on the main run loop. Have you tried commenting that out or waiting for the time interval to finish? What is the purpose of that line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not working because `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:...]` ([reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)) states:

> Creates and returns a new NSTimer object and schedules it on the
>   current run loop in the default mode.

... and you **don't have a run loop**.

You can, for example, create an instance of `NSApplication` (i.e. a proper Cocoa App) in order for this to work (you can probably create your own run loop without creating a Cocoa App, but it would be a fair amount of work).

Answer (score -1):

Try this line of code (1.0/16 instead of 1/16):

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/16) target:self selector:@selector(foo) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Comment: as 1/16 = 0 and 1.0/16 = 0.0625. that's why your timer is not work. Remember: for getting answer in float, at least one value should be in float.

Comment: You are sort of right. 1/16 is an integer operation and results in 0. However, the timer will still work in principle when 0 is given. From the docs: If seconds is less than or equal to 0.0, this method chooses the nonnegative value of 0.1 milliseconds instead.